# Android Studio: Standard size across dynamically created buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have created a loop to generate a certain amount of buttons, the number of buttons created is between 3 and 8. What I am trying to do is have these buttons appear in the center of the screen but have the same standard square format whether there be 3, 4, 5, etc. Currently the fewer there are, the more rectangular the buttons appear.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.space_layout);
        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            myButton.setText("");
            myButton.setId(00 + i);
            layout.addView(myButton);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(myButton));
        }
```

Layout Declaration in XML

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/space_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="8"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_above="@+id/button0"
android:layout_below="@+id/definitiontxt">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to use `layout-weight` attribute and set it to 1. This would cause, that every button would take the same amount of space, so it should make all of your generated buttons 'duplicated'.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your layout params with width=0(if linearlayout is horizontal) or height=0(if linearlayout is vertical).

Try this code:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.space_layout);
        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            Button myButton = new Button(this);
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
            myButton.setText("");
            myButton.setId(00 + i);
            layout.addView(myButton);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(myButton));
        }
```

Because the weight will be only effected when the width is set to zero.
Also,set the orientation of your Linear layout.

Hope it can help.